# How can I show the logged-in user in Power Apps Portal what their form submissions are?

Tags: configuration, dynamics-crm, relationship, powerapps-portal

### The setup

I have a Power Apps Portal with the following pages:

1. Prequalification page. This has an entity form embedded inside it. The entity form is linked to the custom entity SupplierPrequal. When the user fills in and submits that form, they are redirected to the next page.
2. Submission List page. This has a List embedded inside it. The list should show each of the logged-in user's form submissions.
3. Submission Edit page. This has an entity form embedded inside it. The entity form is linked to the same custom entity SupplierPrequal and lets them attach files to a previous submission.

### The problem I am facing

On the Submission List page, it shows submissions of users other than the logged in user. Here is a screenshot. You can see that the metadata for fields like [Created By] does not identify the user who submitted the form.

I was able to autopopulate the field [00_lkp_UserSubmittingForm] with the logged in username. Unfortunately this is not a unique identifier, and is also editable by the user.

[image]

### I see these potential solutions, and would appreciate your advice

- Change the metadata so that instead of recording the field [Created By] as "SYSTEM", it will record the logged-in user's unique identifier. Then change the view's filtering conditions, so [Created By] equals the current user.
- Change the metadata so that a new field such as [00_lkp_UserSubmittingForm] will be autopopulated with the logged-in user's unique identifier. Then change the view's filtering conditions, so that new field equals the current user.
- I suspect that both these approaches will require a lookup of the [External Identity] entity's field [Username]. They will probably involve configuring the entity form's tabs "Entity Reference" and "Entity Form Metadata" in Portal Management.

### What I've researched

- [This link](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/09/identify-the-source-of-records-created-from-microsoft-portal-in-dynamics-365/) describes a similar problem, although the solution is for a CRM Portal, not a Power Apps Portal.
- [This link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Current-logged-in-username/td-p/2449/page/2) addresses the issue for a Canvas App, not a Portal App
- [This link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Portals/Associate-current-portal-user-on-insert-option-not-available-on/td-p/405915) apparently got it working, although I am still trying to understand what I need to configure.

Comment: Please note that I am currently going through the Microsoft e-learning to get familiar with Dynamics. Right now I'm hoping for simple advice that I can implement without familiarity with the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem statement you wish to filter out Entity List, in your case Submission List page based on your logged in user.

**As you might now, every user in Portals is a Contact record in CRM.**

If I see your `createdby`, `modifiedby` and `owner` fields, I believe you have some background logic which runs under System (user) and does the required.

You have 2 way to solve your issue:

1. Either change your background logic to run under the context of running user. This will `createdby`, `modifiedby` and `owner` as running user and not System.
2. or you create a lookup field `00_lkp_UserSubmittingForm` I say lookup and not plain text field. This lookup field will have relationship with contact. So you can autofill this field (lookup) with contact as user. In this way you get unique value in your `00_lkp_UserSubmittingForm` field. Because it has unique guid for each user (in turn a contact)

Now with above any method what you get is current user (unique).

Then you can follow any of the below article to solve your issue.

1. List item

In Entity List itself, there is one option to add Filter Condition. Please check below:
[Article Ref](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/266160/how-to-filter-entity-list-record-based-on-portal-logged-in-user-and-its-account/751252)
[image]

2. Or follow this [article](https://readyxrm.blog/2017/11/30/filter-a-dynamics-365-portal-entity-list/)

Comment: Hello AnkUser, thanks for your answer. Could you please expand on solution 1.? 
I did not set up any background logic to run under System (user).